# How can we keep the subtitle track when converting from MKV to MP4 with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, conversion, subtitles, mkv

I have an MKV with integrated subtitles as such:

[image]

I want to keep "English [Full] - [English]" when converting to MP4.

Currently I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i myMovie.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy myMovieMP4.mp4
```

The conversion works but the subtitles don't show up on the screen and if I go in "Subtitles" and select this, it still doesn't show up:

[image]

Ideally, I would like to those subtitles to automatically show up when running the .mp4 (as though it was hardcoded into the video). Is there any known way of doing that?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You can find detailed answer on your question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214199/how-do-i-add-and-or-keep-subtitles-when-converting-video)

**Basically you need to add "-map" parameter to your command.**

```
ffmpeg -i myMovie.mkv -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s:0 myMovieMP4.mp4
```

`-map 0:v:0` means, that you want to pick first video track from first input file "myMovie.mkv".

`-map 0:a:0` means, that you want to pick first audio track from first input file "myMovie.mkv".

`-map 0:s:0` means, that you want to pick first subtitles track from first input file "myMovie.mkv".

You can can input ffmpeg "myMovie.mkv" to look at the list of streams in the file.

**This command with "-map 0" will put all available tracks into the output file:**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -c:s mov_text output.mp4
```

[Selecting streams with the -map option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)

To burn-in subtitles you can read the link at the top of the message or find another subject here at the stackexchange.

**Basically you can burn-in subtitles from MKV to MP4 using this command**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0]subtitles=input.mkv:si=0[v]" `-map "[v]"` -map 0:a:0 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

`[0:v:0]` - means, that you want to take first video stream from input file.

`:si=0` - means, that you want to take first subtitle stream from input file

`-map "[v]"` - means, that you want to put into your output video processed by filter_complex stream (video + subtitles).

`-map 0:a:0` - means, that you want to take first audio stream from input file

Audio will be copied, video stream will be reencoded.
`-c:v libx264` - reencode to x264